# AS3 dispatchEvent not working

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, event-handling, dispatchevent, event-listener

I've searched other examples of dispatching events and none of them have helped me.

Here is what I have so far. I know that the event listener is added successfully, but the event is never dispatched.

In a .mxml file:

```
function foo():void {

    var eventClassObj:MyEventClass = new MyEventClass();


}
```

In a separate .as file:

```
public class MyEventClass extends EventDispatcher 
{

    public function MyEventClass(target:flash.events.IEventDispatcher = null) 
    {

                    //ADD EVENT LISTENER
        this.addEventListener("test", testFunc, true);



                    //DEBUGGING PRINT STATEMENTS
        var str:String;
        if (this.hasEventListener("test")) {
                str = "EVENT LISTENER ADDED";
        } else {
                str = "NO LISTENER";
        }

        ExternalInterface.call("console.log", str);

                    //DISPATCH EVENT
        this.dispatchEvent(new Event("test", true));
    }


    //THIS MUST EXECUTE WHEN EVENT DISPATCHED
    private function testFunc(e:Event):void {
        ExternalInterface.call("console.log", "dispatch event successful");
    }
}
```

I am completely new to ActionScript3. Do you know why the event is never dispatched? My output in the console for running this would only be:

```
EVENT LISTENER ADDED
```

while my expected output is:

```
EVENT LISTENER ADDED
dispatch event successful
```

I don't see why this wouldn't work.

Comment: It's been a while, but I'm guessing your event listener is not triggered b/c the thing that is dispatching the event is not on the Flash display list. MXML objects are event dispatchers, by definition. So you don't need a separate `EventDispatcher` -- you can listen for and dispatch your "test" even right from the MXML class. If you really want to have another class listen for the event, you need to add it to the display list (make it a `UIComponent` or w/special care you can use `Sprite`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem stems from the way how you add event listener. You set `useCapture` as `true` and such setting prevents listener from reaction to bubbling event.

If you change following row:

```
this.addEventListener("test", testFunc, true);
```

to:

```
this.addEventListener("test", testFunc);
```

event will be handled by your `testFunc`.